# Java - javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.LinkageError in Jboss

Tags: java, jboss, classloader, linkageerror

Am getting a Java Linkage error when am browsing through the JSF application pages. The application is been deployed in Jboss-eap -5.1

Error trace:

```
2013-10-30 14:16:54,559 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080-4)
    java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation:
        when resolving field "NODESET" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) of the referring class, javax/xml/xpath/XPathConstants,
        and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for the field's resolved type, javax/xml/namespace/QName, have different Class objects for that type
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving field "NODESET" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) of the referring class, javax/xml/xpath/XPathConstants, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for the field's resolved type, javax/xml/namespace/QName, have different Class objects for that type
    at com.sun.faces.application.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
```

Could you please suggest what might me the possible cause or if any one had faced a similar issue, how to resolve it?
Thanks in advance,
rdgs,
RK

Comment: I believe that the classloader for your application has access to a JAR containing the class `javax.xml.namespace.QName` which is also loaded by the boot classloader. Search your JARs, remove any that contains the mentioned class (there may even be more than one) and try again.

Comment: ◦rt.jar which is in part of jre system lib also contains class javax.xml.namespace.QName [2351 bytes, jvm >= 1.5 ] Is there any way that on runtime Jboss picks the jar related to the application from the EAR

Comment: `rt.jar` is loaded by the boot classloader. I doubt JBoss picks it up too. If *there is no other JAR in the classpath of your app containing `QName`*, then the error may have another reason. But check the JARs of your *deployed* application to be certain. Also check the classpath of the server; is it altered in some way that has added a JAR containing `QName`?

Answer (score 0):

`rt.jar` already contain `QName class`, so need to remove `QName class` from the `jaxrpc.jar` or any other jar having QName class with same package i.e `javax.xml.namespace` (extract the jar, remove QName class(from `javax.xml.namespace`) and re-jar it).